# Magento 2 - How to fix "Incompatible argument type: ... Actual type: array; File:"

Tags: magento2, product

I'm using Magento 2.3.3.

I created a plugin that can edit product at the frontend. The plugin works fine. But it error when running setup:di:compile.

> Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Escaper. Actual type: array; File:.../app/code/.../xxx.php

Here is my code,

```
class Edit extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;

        parent::__construct($context,
        $jsonEncoder,$attributeSetFactory,$registry,$productHelper,$data);
        $this->setData('area','adminhtml');
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('product_edit');
        $this->setUseContainer(true);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
     ...................
```

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `__construct` method with below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
    $this->_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    parent::__construct($context, $jsonEncoder, $attributeSetFactory, $registry, $productHelper, $escaper, $data);
    $this->setData('area','adminhtml');
}
```

Execute:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thank you very much.